# Can SQL Server Compact Edition be used as a standalone database that I can have arbitrary programs use for storage?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can SQL Server Compact Edition be used as a standalone database that I can have arbitrary programs use for storage just like if the service-based SQL Server Express or regular editions were installed?  Or is it only for use by Visual Studio projects as embedded database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compact Edition must run in-process with an application.
It cannot be used just by itself.

Also, it has no stored procedures or triggers.

Comment: That does not mean it can only be run through Visual Studio. You can open the database in SQL Server for example

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, you just need the appropriate data provider

> Access you data easily
>
> Connect to your SQL Server Compact databases easily from both managed and
> unmanaged code by using the included ADO.NET Data Provider or the OLEDB Provider

From [this page](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx).

Comment: What if I'm not developing an app but rather want to point an existing app at the SQL Compact database?

Comment: What language is the existing app written in?

Comment: No idea.  That's the root of my question though (I will edit the question to clarify this).  I have an arbitrary program that can (for example) use an ODBC datasource to connect to SQL Server using the SQL Native library (again, just example).  [Also, odbc isn't involved here but the ODBC admin interface is the tool that defines the datasource and the connectivity library.]  But even if the app was .NET, if I didn't have source I assume this wouldn't make a difference.